# Can not send curl request. Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: http, curl, https, request, postman

I successfully sent request with postman with basic authorization and 1 custom header - token.
Now I need to sent the same request using curl.
This is how postman parameters look like:

[image]

And this is my curl command:

```
curl -k -u my@mail.com:1Qwer432 -H "CERequestToken: 46Yx2fo4t5+p1IX" https://mysite/v54/api/contracts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add --anyauth , you're using http_basic_auth, an "insecure" auth that curl refuse to use by default, i think. don't quote me on it though

Comment: This doesn't work: curl --insecure --anyauth -u my@main.com:1Qwer432 -H "CERequestToken: 46Yx2fo4t5+p1IXH" https://mysite/v54/api/contracts --anyauth

Comment: add `--verbose` and post the output..

Comment: @hanshenrik http://pastie.org/10925949

Comment: best guess: the `46Yx2fo4t5+p1IXH` request token has expired. can postman still send with that token?

Comment: scrub that - Postman logged in with a username/password for "HTTP Basic authentication", curl did not.

Comment: @hanshenrik postman was ok with this token.

Comment: @hanshenrik  I noticed that it desn't work even in requests, where there is no need in token. Something wrong in username-password. But what can be wrong? I just copy/paste it. It is 100% same in pastman and here...

Comment: i don't know. do you have PHP installed? http://paste.debian.net/786360/

Comment: @hanshenrik gonna try this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem is that curl does not save cookies. And it's necessary to send cookies with request.